# How to save unittest.TestResult

Tags: python

If I try to pickle unittest.TestResult in the obvious way

```
    import pickle
    import unittest

    pickle_file = open( "temp" + ".pickle", 'w' )
    u=unittest.TestResult()
    pickle.dump( u, pickle_file  )
```

I get the error (with Python 2.7)

```
    TypeError: can't pickle file objects
```

This used to work in Python 2.6, but in 2.7 and later it appears that file descriptors were added to the `TestResult` class.  So what is the recommended way to save test results?  Do I have to do it the hard way and manually save each of the fields?

Comment: If you're only interested in reviewing results and dont need the state of the actual TestResults, you could try using nose's XML output .  https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace file type fields.

```
import pickle
import unittest

pickle_file = open("temp" + ".pickle", 'wb')
u = unittest.TestResult()
for k, v in vars(u).items():
    if isinstance(v, file): # if not picklable(v):
        setattr(u, k, None)
pickle.dump(u, pickle_file)
```

Or define your own pickler:

```
import pickle
import unittest

class SafePickler(pickle.Pickler):
    def save(self, obj):
        try:
            pickle.Pickler.save(self, obj)
        except TypeError, e:
            pickle.Pickler.save(self, None)

pickle_file = open("temp" + ".pickle", 'wb')
u = unittest.TestResult()
SafePickler(pickle_file).dump(u)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had hoped that the unittest developers had a better way of saving results, but I guess this will work.